# Can someone explain in plain English what the iterations argument means in sankeyNetwork()?

Tags: javascript, r, networkd3

Regarding the `sankeyNetwork()` function from the `networkD3` R pacakge, I read from another post that I can set the `iterations` argument to 0 to have my nodes arranged as they appear in the data.  Can someone explain though what this argument actually does?  I have no clue from the documentation.

Here's what the documentation says regarding `iterations`:

numeric. Number of iterations in the diagramm layout for computation of the depth (y-position) of each node. Note: this runs in the browser on the client so don't push it too high.

Comment: Link the documentation

Comment: [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/networkD3/versions/0.4/topics/sankeyNetwork)

Comment: My guess is that each iteration takes a layout as input and spits out an optimized layout as output. Beyond that I suspect you'll have to look at the code! This link might be useful: https://bost.ocks.org/mike/sankey/

Comment: @dash2, thanks but I my knowledge of javascript is nill.  That's why I'm using the R package . . .

Comment: In plain English, it’s the number of times the algorithm attempts to optimize the location of each node.

Comment: for a more technical explanation, you can read about [Iterative method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterative_method)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In plain English, the `iterations` argument (of `sankeyNetwork()` in `networkD3`) sets the number of times the algorithm attempts to optimize the location of each node. For a more technical explanation of what that means, you can read about [Iterative method on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterative_method).

Comment: Thanks, thhttps://stackoverflow.com/users/4389763/cj-yetmanis is exactly the type of answer I was looking for.